# Error [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6

Tags: java

Updating property file:

> C:\Users\hiruna\Documents\NetBeansProjects\School_Database\build\built-clean.properties
>   Deleting directory
>   C:\Users\hiruna\Documents\NetBeansProjects\School_Database\build
>   clean: init: deps-jar: Created dir:
>   C:\Users\hiruna\Documents\NetBeansProjects\School_Database\build
>   Updating property file:
>   C:\Users\hiruna\Documents\NetBeansProjects\School_Database\build\built-jar.properties
>   Created dir:
>   C:\Users\hiruna\Documents\NetBeansProjects\School_Database\build\classes
>   Created dir:
>   C:\Users\hiruna\Documents\NetBeansProjects\School_Database\build\empty
>   Created dir:
>   C:\Users\hiruna\Documents\NetBeansProjects\School_Database\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
>   Compiling 8 source files to
>   C:\Users\hiruna\Documents\NetBeansProjects\School_Database\build\classes

**warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
1 warning**

compile:

> Created dir:
>   C:\Users\hiruna\Documents\NetBeansProjects\School_Database\dist
>   Copying 1 file to
>   C:\Users\hiruna\Documents\NetBeansProjects\School_Database\build Copy
>   libraries to
>   C:\Users\hiruna\Documents\NetBeansProjects\School_Database\dist\lib.
>   Building jar:
>   C:\Users\hiruna\Documents\NetBeansProjects\School_Database\dist\School_Database.jar
>   To run this application from the command line without Ant, try: java
>   -jar "C:\Users\hiruna\Documents\NetBeansProjects\School_Database\dist\School_Database.jar"
>   jar: BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Plz help any solutions ??

Comment: please give us a proper, clear question.

Comment: How can i avoid the warning